# How can I get Windows to let me always boot straight into grub

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, uefi

I dualboot Ubuntu and Windows and have 2 SSD's. The first one, 1TB is dedicated to Windows and the other, 500GB is for Ubuntu. I had it setup to boot into Grub but every time Windows would upgrade or something, it seemed to trash that and the system would just boot straight into Windows. So I have been just hitting F11 on boot to get the options up and then selecting Ubuntu when I need it, which takes me to grub and then I actually select it. All this works, but it's a bit of pain. Is there an easier way to configure this? I don't want to have to set things up again every time Windows updates. Even just defaulting to the BIOS boot menu every startup would do, but I don't see a way in the BIOS to set that (MSI B450 MB).

If it helps:

```
$  efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 2 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0001,0002
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(2,GPT,c6a1dba9-5c97-46d3-b98c-a9bcb9f5184d,0xfa000,0x32000)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...a................
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,1cb82576-8a01-4836-a909-440920fe0ea4,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)
Boot0002* ubuntu    HD(2,GPT,c6a1dba9-5c97-46d3-b98c-a9bcb9f5184d,0xfa000,0x32000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)..BO
```

What's weird about that is the second Ubuntu option points at the 1TB disc (according to the name that comes up in the boot menu), which doesn't have an Ubuntu installation. But it seems to work, and launches the installation on the 500GB disc. This option I had deleted a couple of times, but every time Windows messes with it, it adds that option back.

So hitting Boot0001 or Boot0002 takes me to grub whose menu is:

```
$  awk -F\' '/menuentry / {print $2}' /boot/grub/grub.cfg 
Ubuntu
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-70-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-70-generic (recovery mode)
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-67-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-67-generic (recovery mode)
Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda2)
UEFI Firmware Settings
```

Comment: With UEFI, both Windows updates and Ubuntu/grub updates will reorder UEFI boot to have that system first. Windows and a few newer Ubuntu systems may also update UEFI which resets many UEFI settings to defaults which may also need redoing. And Windows updates may turn fast start up back on, preventing grub from booting Windows.  Its just something you have to manage. You always should be able to boot either system from UEFI boot menu. And then can reset boot order or go into UEFI and update settings.

Answer (score 1):

Change the boot order with efibootmgr so Ubuntu is first:

```
efibootmgr -o 0001,0000
```

Comment: When I run that, it looks good (Boot order is 0001, 0000) but when I restart, it still goes to Windows and the next time I go to Ubuntu, I see the boot order has been changed to 0000, 0001, 0002